# Hibernate-Criteria: Select distinct column from table ordered by another column

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

**What I want to achieve:** Get list of unique ids ordered by another column, using Hibernate Criteria.

**My code so far:**

```
 Criteria crt = createCriteria(); //complex method returning Criteria
                                  //with joined tables, restrictions and ordering
 crt.setProjection( Projections.distinct( Projections.property( "id")));
 List<Integer> ids = crt.list();
```

**What is wrong:** When I set order by column let's say "date" I get query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table \\JOIN, WHERE...\\ ORDER BY date);
```

which is obviously wrong and results in error:

```
ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression
```

**My idea how to solve it:** Somehow force Hibernate to generate this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM (SELECT * FROM table \\JOIN, WHERE...\\ ORDER BY date);
```

**Problems and what I tried:** There is `createCriteria()` method, which I don't want to modify if it's not absolutely necessary. I didn't find a way to use this Criteria as DetachedCriteria.

Comment: You can change a detached criteria to a normal one, if this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot put subqueries into the FROM clause with criteria.

Bug you can:

- Use HQL
- Use plain SQL
- Change to query

Is the id not unique anyway? So why not just put the date into the select clause? It would change the result, except of that you get another column in the result.

```
SELECT distinct date, id
FROM table
ORDER BY date
```

---

Another approach:

```
SELECT min(date), id
FROM table
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY min(date)
```

Something like this:

```
createCriteria(SomeTable.class)
  .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
    .add(Projections.groupProperty("id"))
    .add(Projections.min("date"), "minDate")
  .add(Order.desc("minDate"))
```

Comment: Query is too complicated to use HQL or plain SQL. Id is unique, but I join tables and one Id can appear several times. `crt.setResultTransformer( Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);` doesn't help, because I use also `setFirstResult` and `setMaxResults` and I receive not enough data. And when I put "date" in select clause I don't receive distinct id...

Comment: I see. I had another idea. Hope it helps.